# Disable state management history in Elasticsearch with Open Distro

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I have ElasticSearch on AWS which uses Open Distro rather than Elastics ilm.

When you apply state management for indexes it causes a crazy amount of audit indexes to be created. I would like to just disable this completely.

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/ism/settings/

Apparently it's just done setting `opendistro.index_state_management.history.enabled` to `false` but if I apply it to the `_cluster/settings` it doesn't appear to work.

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "opendistro.index_state_management.history.enabled": false
}
```

Results in:

```
{
  "Message": "Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."
}
```

The setting is also not valid on an index template so I cannot set it there.

How can I disable this audit history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked on GitHub and got an answer:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "opendistro.index_state_management.history.enabled": false
  }
}
```

Need to wrap it with an action of `persistent`.

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/elasticsearch/configuration/